# rsync directory with a lot of files

Tags: rsync

i try to do rsync of directory who cantain lot of files more than 500000 , i got two problem the first one is that rsync stuck trying to build incremental file , because of the huge number of files and the seconde i use this command :

```
   rsync -u login_user -e "ssh -v" --rsync-path="sudo rsync" --ignore-existing -vha --    progress /home/a/b/ remote_host:/tmp/ 

   >> ls /home/a/b/
      test
```

this command copy have a weird behavior , it copy the test file in /tmp/ and create b directory Inside tmp who cantains test file (i Don't know why it create also this directory)

Any idea how to correct these two problems.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're doing --progress, right?

Answer (score 0):

I think the first part of your question may be infrastructure specific. For the latter problem of not copying the directory with `rsync`, I believe you can add '*' after the directory name, e.g. `/home/a/b/*`, to just copy the directory contents.

Comment: Thanks for the eedback , I already tried /home/a/b/* , it gives me the same result , it copies the content but also the parent directory